# ejs template function inside function

Tags: javascript, node.js, kml, ejs

Is there a way for ejs template to call a function inside another function? For example I am trying to do like this:

```
<% function graph(graph) { %>
        <a href="<%= graph.href %>"><%= graph.description %></a>
<% } %>


<% function point(point) { %>

    <Placemark id="<%= point.id %>">
        <description>
        <%= point.Apibudinimas %> <%= point.IP %>
        <![CDATA[

        <% graphs.map(graph) %>

        ]]>
        </description>
    </Placemark>

<% } %>
```

But it says that graphs are undefined...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is saying that "graphs" (with an "s") is undefined and not "graph", correct? Where are you defining the graphs array? Otherwise, the code looks fine.

Comment: Yeas, GRAPHS is undefined. Graphs is defined and filled with render function in node script. I have other functions which are loaded this way and it works. The problem comes when I want to call a function like my code above says...